# Efficiency in Layout PHP

Tags: php, performance

I have a central Theme class that loads up all the different parts of my MVC(L) app.

Right now I'm loading my additional controllers like so:

```
$data['header']                 = $this->theme->controller('content/header');
$data['content_top']            = $this->theme->controller('common/contenttop');
$data['content_top_blocks']     = $this->theme->controller('common/contenttopblocks');
$data['column_left']            = $this->theme->controller('common/columnleft');
$data['breadcrumb']             = $this->theme->controller('common/breadcrumb');
$data['column_right']           = $this->theme->controller('common/columnright');
$data['content_bottom_blocks'] = $this->theme->controller('common/contentbottomblocks');
$data['content_bottom']         = $this->theme->controller('common/contentbottom');
$data['footer']                 = $this->theme->controller('content/footer');
```

It occurred to me that since all the common controllers are always called, it might make sense to move them all to my theme to remove some of the bloat and redundancy, after all OOP is about not having to write the same code over and over.

So I tried it, seems to work fine and looks like so:

```
$this->theme->public_controllers['header'] = 'content/header';
$this->theme->public_controllers['footer'] = 'content/footer';

foreach ($this->theme->public_controllers as $key => $file):
    $data[$key] = $this->theme->controller($file);  
endforeach;
```

But this brings up a couple questions.

If you count the difference in lines, it's 9 vs. 6 ... so that's not really much bloat removal. And this does change the order that the controllers are rendered.

So my question is, number one, since the number of lines saved is only 3, is it worth my time, does it make it easier to read or more correct in terms of code style?

And, will moving the header controller, where the CSS is rendered, off the top of the stack make a difference across different platforms, or does that not matter at all?

Comment: This might be better on _Code Review_, but neither approach looks bad to me. I think I'd mildly agree with the loop change, FWIW. What do you mean by 'difference across different platforms'? Do you mean different server platforms? That should not make a difference, no.

Comment: By different platforms I mean, browsers, PHP versions, devices, and yes server platforms as well.

Comment: It matters where your CSS is rendered, but I'm not aware that browsers will handle that differently. CSS is usually best in the header, as it will be read prior to the document being rendered; if you put it in the footer and it is required for that same page, you can get a 'style flash' between unstyled and styled rendering. I doubt though that browsers will do much different there.

Comment: You should test it in all browsers of course, to _check_ whether it makes a difference `:-)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to halfer for his advice and comments.

I resolved the issue in stack order by simply adding the most common header and footer to the default controllers array in my theme class, and that would then get the number lines down to just 3.  3 vs 9 lines is enough of a difference to warrant changing it.

So now for controllers that need to execute just the default set I have:

```
foreach ($this->theme->get_controllers() as $key => $file):
    $data[$key] = $this->theme->controller($file);  
endforeach;
```

Nice and clean.

If I need to change the header or footer I can do this:

```
$this->theme->set_controller('header', 'shop/header');
```

And if I want to remove a controller that's not needed:

```
$this->theme->unset_controller('breadcrumb');
```

Totally worth the effort, thanks halfer.